# How to sort a Pandas DataFrame according to multiple criteria?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame containing song names, their peak chart positions and the number of weeks they spent at position no 1:

```
                                          Song            Peak            Weeks
76                            Paperback Writer               1               16
117                               Lady Madonna               1                9
118                                   Hey Jude               1               27
22                           Can't Buy Me Love               1               17
29                          A Hard Day's Night               1               14
48                              Ticket To Ride               1               14
56                                       Help!               1               17
109                       All You Need Is Love               1               16
173                The Ballad Of John And Yoko               1               13
85                               Eleanor Rigby               1               14
87                            Yellow Submarine               1               14
20                    I Want To Hold Your Hand               1               24
45                                 I Feel Fine               1               15
60                                 Day Tripper               1               12
61                          We Can Work It Out               1               12
10                               She Loves You               1               36
155                                   Get Back               1                6
8                               From Me To You               1                7
115                              Hello Goodbye               1                7
2                             Please Please Me               2               20
92                   Strawberry Fields Forever               2               12
93                                  Penny Lane               2               13
107                       Magical Mystery Tour               2               16
176                                  Let It Be               2               14
0                                   Love Me Do               4               26
157                                  Something               4                9
166                              Come Together               4               10
58                                   Yesterday               8               21
135                       Back In The U.S.S.R.              19                3
164                         Here Comes The Sun              58               19
96       Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band              63               12
105         With A Little Help From My Friends              63                7
```

I'd like to rank these songs in order of popularity, so I'd like to sort them according to the following criteria: songs that reached the highest position come first, but if there is a tie, the songs that remained in the charts for the longest come first.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Pandas.

Answer (score 33):

On pandas 0.9.1 and higher this should work (this is with 0.10.0b1):

(**Edit:** As of Pandas 0.19, method `sort_index` is deprecated. Prefer [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html?highlight=sort_values#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values))

```
In [23]: songs.sort_index(by=['Peak', 'Weeks'], ascending=[True, False])
Out[23]: 
                                      Song  Peak  Weeks
10                           She Loves You     1     36
118                               Hey Jude     1     27
20                I Want To Hold Your Hand     1     24
22                       Can't Buy Me Love     1     17
56                                   Help!     1     17
76                        Paperback Writer     1     16
109                   All You Need Is Love     1     16
45                             I Feel Fine     1     15
29                      A Hard Day's Night     1     14
48                          Ticket To Ride     1     14
85                           Eleanor Rigby     1     14
87                        Yellow Submarine     1     14
173            The Ballad Of John And Yoko     1     13
60                             Day Tripper     1     12
61                      We Can Work It Out     1     12
117                           Lady Madonna     1      9
8                           From Me To You     1      7
115                          Hello Goodbye     1      7
155                               Get Back     1      6
2                         Please Please Me     2     20
107                   Magical Mystery Tour     2     16
176                              Let It Be     2     14
93                              Penny Lane     2     13
92               Strawberry Fields Forever     2     12
0                               Love Me Do     4     26
166                          Come Together     4     10
157                              Something     4      9
58                               Yesterday     8     21
135                   Back In The U.S.S.R.    19      3
164                     Here Comes The Sun    58     19
96   Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band    63     12
105     With A Little Help From My Friends    63      7
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is possible to have the dataframe re-compute the index according to the new order? (i.e. so that the index associated with each row in the dataframe grows according to the new ordering)

Comment: This is an old question, but just in case someone still needs this.. What you want can be done using [pandas.DataFrame.reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) (try `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`)

Comment: To recompute the indices after sorting, try `df.index = range(len(df))`

Comment: In 0.22.0 `sort_index ` is still available an not marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 23):

Since pandas 0.17.0, [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) is deprecated and replaced by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df.sort_values(['Peak', 'Weeks'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 18):

```
df.sort(['Peak', 'Weeks'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

If you want the sorted result for future use, `inplace=True` is required.

Answer (score 5):

By using [.sort()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html)

```
df.sort(['Peak', 'Weeks'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Will sort into ascending order of peak position, then within that descending order of length in charts.

Comment: yeah, for some reason that's not the case. I thought it should work that way too

Comment: @user1715271 Could you elaborate? ie - what do you actually get?

Comment: @user1715271 You are looking at the DataFrame objected *returned* from the sort, right? The original won't get changed unless you pass `inplace=True` to the sort...

Comment: the second criteria  still sorts ties in the "Peak" column in descending order

Comment: @user1715271 "still sorts ties in the "Peak" column in descending order" - errr - that's what you want isn't it?

Comment: When there's a tie in the "Peak" column, it goes on to sort the "Weeks" column in descending order

Comment: @user1715271 Really - seems okay to me? Well, sort ascending on Peak, then sort it again descending on Weeks and you should get what you're after...

Answer (score 0):

In case, if the dtypes of 'Peak' and 'Week' are not 'int' or 'float', then use the following command.

```
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).sort_values(['Peak', 'Weeks'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas.DataFrame.sort_values
df.sort_values(['Peak', 'Weeks'], ascending=[True, False])

Please find more details around this on