# Sorting Pandas Dataframe by Category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `.xlsx` file with 9 variables of 898 observations. I read in a `.xlsx` file and parsed into a pandas `dataframe`. I tried sorting a pandas `dataframe` column called `product_id` by ascending order, but got all the columns in the result.

I followed the advice from another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636592/how-to-sort-a-pandas-dataframe-according-to-multiple-criteria), but still got an error.

**Question:** How can I get the top 10 highest occurring values from the `product_id` category in ascending order?

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd 
#Import data
trans = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
#parse xlsx file into dataframe
transdata = trans.parse('Orders')
#view head of dataframe
print transdata.head()

   site_id  visitor_id  transaction_id transaction_date  product_id  price  \
0        3       10001           20001       2014-10-31       48165    150   
1        3       10002           20002       2014-10-31       48162    128   
2        3       10002           20003       2014-10-30       48165    150   
3        3       10003           20004       2014-10-31       48815     98   
4        3       10003           20005       2014-10-29       48165    150   

   units  sales_tax   total  
0      1      12.38  162.38  
1      1      10.56  138.56  
2      1      12.38  162.38  
3      1       8.09  106.09  
4      1      12.38  162.38  

grouped = transdata.groupby(['product_id']).size()
print grouped

product_id
36959          78
44524          12
45956          33
46814          11
48162          50
48165         100
48412          12
48478          23
48500          13
48528          14
48552         101
48587         106
48593         104
48628           4
48810          25
48814          16
48815          33
48823          20
49418          11
49444          12
49882         102
51184           2
51380          15
dtype: int64
```

**EDIT:** I tried sorting the pandas dataframe category `product_id` but got rankings of all the columns.

```
grouped = transdata.groupby(['product_id'])
counts = grouped.size().sort()
result = counts.head(10).index
print result

   site_id  visitor_id  transaction_id transaction_date  product_id  price  \
0        3       10001           20001       2014-10-31       48165    150   
1        3       10002           20002       2014-10-31       48162    128   
2        3       10002           20003       2014-10-30       48165    150   
3        3       10003           20004       2014-10-31       48815     98   
4        3       10003           20005       2014-10-29       48165    150   

   units  sales_tax   total  
0      1      12.38  162.38  
1      1      10.56  138.56  
2      1      12.38  162.38  
3      1       8.09  106.09  
4      1      12.38  162.38  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Trending.py", line 14, in <module>
    result = counts.head(10).index
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
```

**Desired output:** A vector with the top highest occuring values from the `product_id` category.

```
product_id
48587         
48593         
49882         
48552         
48165         
36959        
48162          
45956         
48815          
48478
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what output you were expecting? I'm struggling to understand the issue.

Comment: @JDLong I made another edit, sorry for the confusion. I want an output of the top 10 values for the column product_id. I tried sorting, but ended up with the top values for every column.

Comment: So you only want the product ID? If so, then you just select the column with `ranks['product_id']`

Comment: @PaulH I tried the ranks function and the output has five rows of every column. product_id shows only 48165 in all five rows.

Answer (score 0):

From this:

```
grouped = transdata.groupby(by=['product_id'])
```

You just need

```
counts = grouped.size()['product_id']
counts.sort()
counts.head(10)
```

Comment: @ScottDavis the `sort` method of a dataframe returned a sorted dataframe. Are you sure you just don't want the `df.rank(...)` method?

Comment: I deleted the last comment because I edited the original question. I am a new python user and getting the functions mixed up. How can I get a rank of the top 10 product_id's?

Comment: I edited the question to show my data and desired output. After using the sort() function on your edit, the output shows 10 rows of values. One with the row number, another with the 36959 product_id. I need the 10 highest occurring product_id's sorted in ascending order.

Comment: I made your edit, but am not getting the right result. The output was only the first 5 values of the wrong product_id and had other columns as well.

Comment: @ScottDavis post some data that I can use and I'll show you want to do.

Comment: I posted the head of my data. Should I post more? I don't know how to make a reproducible answer in python.

Comment: @ScottDavis see my first code block here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940753/aligning-dataframes-with-same-columns-different-index-levels

Comment: Am I supposed to print counts or set counts.head(10) as an object and print that? Printing counts results in the same result as the last edit. I have five rows of one product plus all the other columns. I'll look at your link.