# Pandas complex sorting

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset with train delays, problem is that the dataset is not indexed by time, but by station name, so I want to get close to a timeline but as you can see below "Dockmyr" is both at index 1 and 5. I want to primarily sort by delay as it is (normally) cumulative but also always group arrival and departure from the same station together, that makes 'direction' descending and 'delay' ascending. Is this possible? 
I use this atm:

```
df_qry.sort_values(by=['delay','direction','station'], ascending=True)
Updated:
df_qry.sort_values(by=['delay','direction','station'], ascending=[True,False,False])
```

```
                 station  train        date           delay direction
23150984     Brattsbacka  10029  2019-06-15               5      dep
23150990         Dockmyr  10029  2019-06-15               5      dep
23151058        Norrfors  10029  2019-06-15               5      dep
23151067         Oxmyran  10029  2019-06-15               5      dep
23151111            Ånge  10029  2019-06-15               6      arr
23150989         Dockmyr  10029  2019-06-15               7      arr
```

```
Want this:
                 station  train        date           delay direction
23150984     Brattsbacka  10029  2019-06-15               5      dep
23150989         Dockmyr  10029  2019-06-15               7      arr
23150990         Dockmyr  10029  2019-06-15               5      dep
23151058        Norrfors  10029  2019-06-15               5      dep
23151067         Oxmyran  10029  2019-06-15               5      dep
23151111            Ånge  10029  2019-06-15               6      arr
```

En route, you arrive at a station and then depart from it, you don't do anything inbetween, and in this case you can see that for the first stretch the delay is increased by 2 mins and then the stop at Dockmyr is decreased with 2 mins to decrease the delay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a Pandas DataFrame according to multiple criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636592/how-to-sort-a-pandas-dataframe-according-to-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you WANT the output to look like.

Comment: Mykola Zotko, it helped with multiple ascend/descend criterias but not with clustering arrival and departure from the same station together. Maybe I have to make a secondary index for that?